# How can I copy and paste the items in a "content control" dropdown into a text file?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

A client sent us the schematic for a new project in a newfangled Microsoft Word document with dropdowns. (Apparently, the dropdowns are called "content controls" in Microsoft parlance.)

I can't seem to get at the contents of those dropdowns in any easy way -- all I seem able to do is to select an item, copy it, then paste it somewhere else, select the next item, copy it, paste it, rinse and repeat ad nauseam. This is not an acceptable method: some of the dropdowns contain hundreds of fairly long items.

Trying to put the document into design mode and looking at the properties of the controls is even worse: I can then see a little screenful of items at a time, but I can't copy any of them to the clipboard.

Converting to a different format, even just to an older version of Word, loses the dropdown contents - you see the default selection (usually placeholder text), and that's it.

Is there any way to get at the content of a Word dropdown that doesn't involve writing some complex VBA code? I don't want to tell the client that we can't accept their choice of document format, but it may come down to that.

Comment: Can you convert it to some other format?

Comment: @Moab: converting to another format loses the contents of the dropdowns.

Comment: I guess if it was easy you would not be asking.....

Comment: See if this can help...http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/extract_data_from_forms.html

Comment: @Moab: nope, that add-in just gets the *selected* items from a form. Which would put me back at "select an item, copy and paste, rinse and repeat", except even worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may do what you need,

1. Save a copy of the file someplace
2. Change the extension of the document to .zip  so if before was ABC.DOCM or ABC.DOCX it is now ABC.Zip
3. double click zip and explore underlying xml. Most likely what you are looking for will be in a folder called Word inside of document.xlm

may have to search a bit to find correct spot if not there

Look for one of the entries you know about. This example is from a dropdown I made for testing that includes "xray"

[image]

4. Copy it away to excel, word or wherever
5. delete or clean off the xml junk.  (For example, Edit replace 
   w:listItem w:value=" with a blank space through out the document)

Comment: OP can also use text to columns feature in excel, with fixed column at `"`, which will put xray/zebra/rose in its own columns, & all other columns could be discarded.

Comment: Far simpler to Save As the document in XML format.

Comment: @harrymc, actually, renaming as zip has a massive advantage over Save As: you can do the former even if you don't have a newish version of Word installed.